# Unable to create User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the ASP.NET Membership class to create user credentials and manage user settings. The code is as below: it's working fine in my local machine but it throws an exception on the production server..  What could be the reason? Can give me a clue? Anyone?

---

```
try
{                
    MembershipUser newUser = 
        Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
}
catch (MembershipCreateUserException ex)
{
    divErrorPanel1.Visible = true;
    ShowErrorMessage(lblMessage, GetErrorMessage(ex.StatusCode));
    return;
}
```

Comment: First of all have you checked your providers on the web.config of your production server?

Comment: Do you use logging? Can you see the error? There are so many possible reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`MembershipCreateUserException.StatusCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipcreateuserexception.statuscode.aspx) property for explaning the exception.

> Gets a description of the reason for the exception.

These are possibilities.

> - "Username already exists. Please enter a different user name.";
> - "A username for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";
> - "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";
> - "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";
> - "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";
> - "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";
> - "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";
> - "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your
>     system administrator.";
> - "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your
>     system administrator.";
> - "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

Answer (score 0):

Try the overloaded method

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;
MembershipUser newuser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, 
   "Give default question as empty", "Give default answer as empty", IsApprovedTrueOrFalse, out status);
```

The current overload you are using never worked for me too. I don't know why so I was forced to use this overload. May be related to some settings in the web.config whether to make some fields required.

Comment: That this overload doesn't work is probably caused by the configuration of the profile that requires a question/answer for password retrieval. If you change that setting in the web.config the overload should work.

Comment: Yes, that should be true. I just don't like meddling with web.config. I will give it a try when next I have the time. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not want to edit the web.config you can also set the preferences in code. It's just more work :)

Answer (score 0):

in your web.config, try setting the following property to false

```
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

in  node